# Breaking acceleration signal into group of subset signal (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have about 5 hours of the acceleration data for a particular user ( the collected data is real life data, which means I don't know what the user is doing at a particular time).

the dataset contains the time stamp in the first column and the acceleration data of 3 axes (X, Y, and Y) in the second, third, fourth columns respectively.

```
Time Stamp   X Data   Y Data   Z Data
```

I would like to divide the data based on the user's activities (which is called Activity Recognition in order to make it easy for the classification).

For example, if the user is walking, extract his signal and store it in an array, if he is typing, the typing data will be extracted and store in another array, and so on. Hence, N number of arrays will be created, each will contain data of specific activity.

by the way, it doesn't matter what is the activity, it is more useful to extract the user's pattern for each part of the original signal ( pattern means, the user's signal looks consistent).

here is an example of the original signal for each axis

[image: Acceleration Data of X axis]

[image: Acceleration Data of Y axis]

[image: Acceleration Data of Z axis]

As we can see, the original signal looks very noisy ( as the user do more than one activity at the same day) therefore, I'd like to divide the signal into subsets based on the user's activity.

Note, the highlighted part in attached pics was just an example of walking data from the original signal. I know it's walking data because as we can see it contains repetitive peaks that normally generated when the user is walking

[here is a sample of my data](https://ufile.io/nm32o)

Really appreciate any help.

Regards.

Comment: Transforming your data (locally) to the frequency domain may be useful. See `fft` in matlab.

Comment: Dear m7913d, I guess it is more complicated than using FFT and unfortunately right now I don't have a clue how to get this done. Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you think so? Have you looked at your FFT?

Comment: I don't know how to utilise FFT for this purpose! could you help me with the code? do you need a sample of my data?

Answer (score 1):

That's a typical use case for a machine learning algorithm! Neural networks are in vogue at the moment, but there are lots of other algorithms to do that as well. Matlab has a neural network toolbox, it even has a GUI. But do not expect it just to plug and play...

If it's just the highlighted part you want to extract (so your use case is very limited) you could just try to do it by hand. Compute some statistic values such as mean, variance and so on. Find the ones that destinguish your region from the rest and use them to find that region.

Comment: dear @ yar, this was just an example of my data. as i have 30 users and for each users 10 files each contains 4 hours of acceleration data. do you have any idea to divide the signal into group of signals please?

Comment: I have uploaded a sample of the collected data and change the content of my question!

Comment: @NeamahAl-Naffakh Well, as I said, it's a typical machine learning classification problem. If you do not know much about the data (and do not want to do it by hand) you can use an unsupervised learning classification algorithm. Nevertheless, doing it right is not a 5-minute task, especially not if you are not familiar with machine learning. Consider doing it by hand with a small feature vector. Also (as m7913d pointed out) have a look at the FT (as part of your feature vector). It's very likely that the FT of the different parts will have peaks at different frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment and supported by yar, the FFT may be an important feature to segment your data. The next code is only a small example of how you could use the FFT. To obtain good results you probably should incorporate it in a machine learning algorithm as suggested by yar.

The idea is to take the FFT locally (1e4 samples) and to look at the differences between the intervals. I applied a simple threshold method the segment your requested part out of the rest.

```
data = importdata('data_big.csv'); % import your data

[b, a] = butter(2, 0.01); % construct a low pass filter, to clean up the FFT output

fftInterval = 1e4; % interval over which the fft is taken
is = 1:floor(size(data, 1)/fftInterval)-1; % indices of intervals to process
amplitudes = zeros(fftInterval,  is(end)); % preallocate memory for amplitude of fft
highlight = zeros(size(data, 1), 1); % preallocate memory for selecting region of interest
for i=is
  range = (1:1e4)+i * 1e4;
  amplitudes(:, i) = filtfilt(b, a, fftshift(db(fft(data(range, 2))))); % calculate fft and obtain amplitude response
  if (amplitudes(5620, i) > 38) % perform a simple threshold to obtain region of interest
    highlight(range) = 5;
  end
end

f = figure;
plot(data(:, 2)); % plot original data
hold on
plot(highlight); % plot region of interest

figure
plot(amplitudes(:, 1:5)); % plot amplitude response for the five first intervals
```

The region of interest plotted over your X data is:
[image]

The amplitude response for the first five intervals are:
[image]

Note that interval 4 and 5 clearly shows peaks around 5620, i.e. the threshold position.

Note that [`cwt`](https://mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwt.html) (Continuous wavelet transform) may be a good alternative for the multiple calls to fft.

Comment: Dear@m7913d, thank you so much for your help. i have some questions please, if i am not wrong, it seems to me that you extracted the highlighted data in the graph if yes, where is the values of these data please? i mean could you please save the original values of the extracted part into an array ( which contains the Time Stamp, X, Y, Z axes values). Kind Regards.

Comment: The `highlight` variable is `5` for the selected part. If you want to obtain the data of these points, you can use logical indexing as follows: `data(highlight == 5, i)` for the ith column. Is this what you want?